# Testing kernel module for Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, android-source

I've built an Android Linux kernel module (Android 2.3.1, Linux 2.6.32). Now I need to test it for proper functioning. But there is a risk that in case of any problems with the module it will be automatically loaded after reboot, so I'll have no further access to the device. Is it possible to load the module in such a way that after reboot it will not be loaded again?

Comment: AFAIK, linux kernel modules are not loaded after reboot if you store them somewhere outside the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/`. So, if you load it manually with `insmod` - the module will not be loaded automatically after reboot. Looks like /etc/modules.conf is a place where automatically loaded drivers are specified.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the .ko to the SD card of the device, and load it from there. It can placed somewhere else (e.g. create a new directory under `/data`, it is mounted RW), just use `adb push` to copy it to the device.